# Is it possible to have a .js page read a value from a .ejs page?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm new to all things programming and I'm trying to create a website where the end goal is to have a database of golf scorecards and organized by date and course name.

I have started out using mongodb as my database and I am connecting to it using mongoose. Currently I have it sorted out that I can get a dynamic set of dates to appear.

My next step, and where I am stuck, is that after I click on said date, the scorecard for that particular date should be the only thing that comes up. However, instead, it will show all of the scorecards.
[current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIow0.jpg) (yes I know the numbers for the totals don't add up)

Here is a snippet of my app.js

```
app.get("/courses", function(req, res) {
//create all the arrays for all the variables for the scorecard
  var arrayCourseDate = []
  var arrayWalkRide = []
  var arrayPaired =[]
  var arrayArinColor = []
  var arrayJasonColor = []
  var arrayArin1 = []
  var arrayArin2 = []
  var arrayArin3 = []
  var arrayArin4 = []
  var arrayArin5 = []
  var arrayArin6 = []
  var arrayArin7 = []
  var arrayArin8 = []
  var arrayArin9 = []
  var arrayArin10 = []
  var arrayArin11 = []
  var arrayArin12 = []
  var arrayArin13 = []
  var arrayArin14 = []
  var arrayArin15 = []
  var arrayArin16 = []
  var arrayArin17 = []
  var arrayArin18 = []
  var arrayArinTotal = []
  var arrayJason1 = []
  var arrayJason2 = []
  var arrayJason3 = []
  var arrayJason4 = []
  var arrayJason5 = []
  var arrayJason6 = []
  var arrayJason7 = []
  var arrayJason8 = []
  var arrayJason9 = []
  var arrayJason10 = []
  var arrayJason11 = []
  var arrayJason12 = []
  var arrayJason13 = []
  var arrayJason14 = []
  var arrayJason15 = []
  var arrayJason16 = []
  var arrayJason17 = []
  var arrayJason18 = []
  var arrayJasonTotal = []
  var arrayPar1 = []
  var arrayPar2 = []
  var arrayPar3 = []
  var arrayPar4 = []
  var arrayPar5 = []
  var arrayPar6 = []
  var arrayPar7 = []
  var arrayPar8 = []
  var arrayPar9 = []
  var arrayPar10 = []
  var arrayPar11 = []
  var arrayPar12 = []
  var arrayPar13 = []
  var arrayPar14 = []
  var arrayPar15 = []
  var arrayPar16 = []
  var arrayPar17 = []
  var arrayPar18 = []
  var arrayParTotal = []

// use mongoose to query a database called Outings.
  Outing.find(function(err, outings) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // create a variable that counts all the entries
      var numberOfEntries = outings.length

      //beginning of the for each loop that pushes all the variables to their respective arrays
      outings.forEach(function(outing) {
        arrayCourseDate.push(outing.courseDate);
        arrayWalkRide.push(outing.walkRide)
        arrayPaired.push(outing.paired)
        arrayArinColor.push(outing.color.Arin)
        arrayArin1.push(outing.hole1.Arin)
        arrayArin2.push(outing.hole2.Arin)
        arrayArin3.push(outing.hole3.Arin)
        arrayArin4.push(outing.hole4.Arin)
        arrayArin5.push(outing.hole5.Arin)
        arrayArin6.push(outing.hole6.Arin)
        arrayArin7.push(outing.hole7.Arin)
        arrayArin8.push(outing.hole8.Arin)
        arrayArin9.push(outing.hole9.Arin)
        arrayArin10.push(outing.hole10.Arin)
        arrayArin11.push(outing.hole11.Arin)
        arrayArin12.push(outing.hole12.Arin)
        arrayArin13.push(outing.hole13.Arin)
        arrayArin14.push(outing.hole14.Arin)
        arrayArin15.push(outing.hole15.Arin)
        arrayArin16.push(outing.hole16.Arin)
        arrayArin17.push(outing.hole17.Arin)
        arrayArin18.push(outing.hole18.Arin)
        arrayArinTotal.push(outing.total.Arin)
        arrayJasonColor.push(outing.color.Jason)
        arrayJason1.push(outing.hole1.Jason)
        arrayJason2.push(outing.hole2.Jason)
        arrayJason3.push(outing.hole3.Jason)
        arrayJason4.push(outing.hole4.Jason)
        arrayJason5.push(outing.hole5.Jason)
        arrayJason6.push(outing.hole6.Jason)
        arrayJason7.push(outing.hole7.Jason)
        arrayJason8.push(outing.hole8.Jason)
        arrayJason9.push(outing.hole9.Jason)
        arrayJason10.push(outing.hole10.Jason)
        arrayJason11.push(outing.hole11.Jason)
        arrayJason12.push(outing.hole12.Jason)
        arrayJason13.push(outing.hole13.Jason)
        arrayJason14.push(outing.hole14.Jason)
        arrayJason15.push(outing.hole15.Jason)
        arrayJason16.push(outing.hole16.Jason)
        arrayJason17.push(outing.hole17.Jason)
        arrayJason18.push(outing.hole18.Jason)
        arrayJasonTotal.push(outing.total.Jason)
        arrayPar1.push(outing.hole1.Par)
        arrayPar2.push(outing.hole2.Par)
        arrayPar3.push(outing.hole3.Par)
        arrayPar4.push(outing.hole4.Par)
        arrayPar5.push(outing.hole5.Par)
        arrayPar6.push(outing.hole6.Par)
        arrayPar7.push(outing.hole7.Par)
        arrayPar8.push(outing.hole8.Par)
        arrayPar9.push(outing.hole9.Par)
        arrayPar10.push(outing.hole10.Par)
        arrayPar11.push(outing.hole11.Par)
        arrayPar12.push(outing.hole12.Par)
        arrayPar13.push(outing.hole13.Par)
        arrayPar14.push(outing.hole14.Par)
        arrayPar15.push(outing.hole15.Par)
        arrayPar16.push(outing.hole16.Par)
        arrayPar17.push(outing.hole17.Par)
        arrayPar18.push(outing.hole18.Par)
        arrayParTotal.push(outing.totalPar)
      }); // end for each loop

      //beginning of section that allows me to use the right side variables from this page to set their value in the ejs page of whatever is on the left

      res.render("newCourses", {
        numberOfEntries: numberOfEntries,
        arrayCourseDate: arrayCourseDate,
        arrayPaired: arrayPaired,
        arrayWalkRide: arrayWalkRide,
        arrayArinColor: arrayArinColor,
        arrayJasonColor: arrayJasonColor,
        arrayArin1: arrayArin1,
        arrayArin2: arrayArin2,
        arrayArin3: arrayArin3,
        arrayArin4: arrayArin4,
        arrayArin5: arrayArin5,
        arrayArin6: arrayArin6,
        arrayArin7: arrayArin7,
        arrayArin8: arrayArin8,
        arrayArin9: arrayArin9,
        arrayArin10: arrayArin10,
        arrayArin11: arrayArin11,
        arrayArin12: arrayArin12,
        arrayArin13: arrayArin13,
        arrayArin14: arrayArin14,
        arrayArin15: arrayArin15,
        arrayArin16: arrayArin16,
        arrayArin17: arrayArin17,
        arrayArin18: arrayArin18,
        arrayArinTotal: arrayArinTotal,
        arrayJason1: arrayJason1,
        arrayJason2: arrayJason2,
        arrayJason3: arrayJason3,
        arrayJason4: arrayJason4,
        arrayJason5: arrayJason5,
        arrayJason6: arrayJason6,
        arrayJason7: arrayJason7,
        arrayJason8: arrayJason8,
        arrayJason9: arrayJason9,
        arrayJason10: arrayJason10,
        arrayJason11: arrayJason11,
        arrayJason12: arrayJason12,
        arrayJason13: arrayJason13,
        arrayJason14: arrayJason14,
        arrayJason15: arrayJason15,
        arrayJason16: arrayJason16,
        arrayJason17: arrayJason17,
        arrayJason18: arrayJason18,
        arrayJasonTotal: arrayJasonTotal,
        arrayPar1: arrayPar1,
        arrayPar2: arrayPar2,
        arrayPar3: arrayPar3,
        arrayPar4: arrayPar4,
        arrayPar5: arrayPar5,
        arrayPar6: arrayPar6,
        arrayPar7: arrayPar7,
        arrayPar8: arrayPar8,
        arrayPar9: arrayPar9,
        arrayPar10: arrayPar10,
        arrayPar11: arrayPar11,
        arrayPar12: arrayPar12,
        arrayPar13: arrayPar13,
        arrayPar14: arrayPar14,
        arrayPar15: arrayPar15,
        arrayPar16: arrayPar16,
        arrayPar17: arrayPar17,
        arrayPar18: arrayPar18,
        arrayParTotal: arrayParTotal,
      }) // end newCourses variable list

    }
  })

});
```

here is a snippet of my newCourses.ejs page

```
<!-- course dates -->
<div class="date mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">

<p>

<% for(var i=0; i<numberOfEntries; i++){ %>


  <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" name="button" value="<%= arrayCourseDate[i] %>" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseScoreCardDate" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseScoreCardDate">
      <%= arrayCourseDate[i] %>

   </button>
<% } %>

</p>
<!-- end course dates -->
<div class="collapse" id="collapseScoreCardDate">
  <!-- The scorecard -->
  <% for(var i=0; i<numberOfEntries; i++){ %>
      <div class="buttoncard shadow-lg rounded">
 <!-- what i need is to take the date and then do a new find for that specific date. -->
 <table class="table table-secondary text-dark table-striped">

   <% for(var i=0; i<numberOfEntries; i++){ %>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">walk/ride</th>
       <th scope="col"> Color </th>
       <th scope="col">Hole</th>
       <th>1</th>
       <th>2</th>
       <th>3</th>
       <th>4</th>
       <th>5</th>
       <th>6</th>
       <th>7</th>
       <th>8</th>
       <th>9</th>
       <th>10</th>
       <th>11</th>
       <th>12</th>
       <th>13</th>
       <th>14</th>
       <th>15</th>
       <th>16</th>
       <th>17</th>
       <th>18</th>
       <th class=table-light scope="col">Total</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><%=arrayWalkRide[i]%> </td>
       <td><%=arrayArinColor[i]%> </td>
       <th scope="row">Arin</th>
       <td><%=arrayArin1[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin2[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin3[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin4[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin5[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin6[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin7[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin8[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin9[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin10[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin11[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin12[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin13[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin14[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin15[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin16[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin17[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayArin18[i]%></td>
       <td class=table-light><%=arrayArinTotal[i]%></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>

       <th scope="row">paired</th>
       <td> <%=arrayJasonColor[i]%></td>
       <th scope="row">Jason</th>
       <td><%=arrayJason1[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason2[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason3[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason4[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason5[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason6[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason7[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason8[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason9[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason10[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason11[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason12[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason13[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason14[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason15[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason16[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason17[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayJason18[i]%></td>
       <td class=table-light><%=arrayJasonTotal[i]%></td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="table-success">
       <td><%=arrayPaired[i]%></td>
       <th scope="row"> </th>
       <th scope="row">Par</th>
       <td><%=arrayPar1[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar2[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar3[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar4[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar5[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar6[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar7[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar8[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar9[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar10[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar11[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar12[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar13[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar14[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar15[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar16[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar17[i]%></td>
       <td><%=arrayPar18[i]%></td>
       <td class=table-light><%=arrayParTotal[i]%></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <% } %>
 </table>

      </div>
      <!--  end of scorecard -->
      <% } %>
</div>
</div>
```

How I would like to make it work is to have mongoose run a query to get the dates and then, once clicked, have another mongoose query specific to only that date and therefor not needing all the arrays and variables in the for each loop. I just don't know how to get the app.js page to read a value from the .ejs page.

Answer (score 0):

The link that is clicked in the .ejs page that you want to specify a specific date should add that date as a query parameter to the link.  So, instead of just linking to `/courses`, you would build a link such as `/courses?date=xxxx` with that query parameter set for the specific date you want (`xxxx` would be the date you want in a format of your choice).

Then, your Express route handler can check `req.query.date` and, if it has a meaningful value, then you modify your query for just that date.

So, inside your route:

```
app.get("/courses", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.date) {
         // run query for a specific date only
    } else {
         // query for all dates
    }
    .....
});
```

A query parameter is a simple way of passing arguments to a link to modify the target of the link without having to create a new route just for that set of argumentsw.  If you look at Google search links, you will see there are lots of things in a query parameter after you search as they are doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight and quick reply. I'll have to do my research to build it all out. I see and appreciate the suggestion for the app.js side. I will have to see how to build it out on the ejs side to add the query parameter.

Comment: @JasonG - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points her on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.